# Finding the basis and dimension of a subspace - question 01

Tags: vector-spaces

I was working on some subspaces, basis and dimensions work and came across the following question I couldn't obtain an answer for and was wondering if anyone could offer me some help. The question is as follows:

Consider the following.

W = {(s + 3t, t, s, 7s − t): s and t are real numbers}

Find a basis for the subspace W of $R^4$ (in vector form) and determine the dimension of the subspace W of R4.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

How $s(1, 0, 1, 7)+t(3, 1, 0 -1)$ then $\{(1, 0, 1, 7), (3, 1, 0 -1)\}$ is a basis because are independent.

Other form to see. Is a plane for the origen in $\mathbb{R}^4$